# How can I use Reference Tools Translation from VBA with Mac Excel Office 2011

Tags: macos, excel, ms-office, vba

In Mac Excel 2011 you can access a translation tool from the drop down menus Toolbox > Reference Tools > Translation.

Is there anyway to access this from VBA (for MAC Excel)?

I have googled for hours but been unable to find any examples or references to using it.

Alternatively, is there any other translation tools (like Google Translate) that can be accessed from VBA in Mac Excel 2011?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell after much research, is that you can NOT use it. You can open it up using menu commands but there is no way to get the result of the translation and bring it back into your VBA.